# Отключить принудительное автозаполение в поле ввода телефона

Tags: android, kotlin, клавиатура, android-xml

Есть поле ввода телефонного номера. Сюда автоматически подставляется номер телефона и при этом он затирает код страны и вызывает зависание, а после и завершение приложения.
Я добавил поле android:importantForAutofill="no" это помогло решить проблему с автоматическим автозаполнением но при принудительном автозаполнении, все равно можно вставить данные.
Как запретить принудительное автозаполнение?

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilPhone"
        style="@style/InvertedTextInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tilCountry"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tilCountry"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilCountry">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiPhone"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            style="@style/InvertedEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/auth_label_phone" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Обновление

Принудительное автозаполнение включается при продолжительном нажатии на строку ввода, и там в контекстном меню есть пункт AutoFill.

Comment: "Принудительное автозаполнение" - не знакомый термин, это что такое?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте полю ввода:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```